# Complex MySQL cmd with JOINS and Counters doesnt work

Tags: mysql, sqlfiddle

I am working on [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6dc97/27) and cant get the command working. Here the command:

```
SET @n := 1;
SET @start := '2013-07-22 10:00:01';
SET @end := '2013-07-22 10:00:02';
SET @register := 40001;

SELECT * FROM 
    (
    SELECT
        `realvalues`.`Timestamp`,
        `realvalues`.`Value` * `register`.`Factor`,
        @x := @x + 1 AS rank
    FROM
        `realvalues`,
        (SELECT @x := 0) t            
    WHERE
        `realvalues`.`Register` = register AND
        `realvalues`.`Timestamp` BETWEEN start AND end
    JOIN
        `register`
    ON
        `register`.`DeviceID` = `realvalues`.`DeviceID` AND
        `register`.`Register` = `realvalues`.`Register`
    ) a
WHERE
    rank MOD ? = n
```

Does anybody know where the command fails? MySQL error reporting isnt very usefull.

[EDIT] The Value is now duplicated with Factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many many things wrong with your query. However, the error that is being reported in your fiddle is:

> ...check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BETWEEN start AND end JOIN `register` ON ...

Your syntax for `BETWEEN` is incorrect. There should be no `IS` token before `BETWEEN`. Correct syntax is:

```
<value> BETWEEN <lower-bound-inclusive> AND <upper-bound-inclusive>
```

Other problems include:

- `start`, `end`, and `n` are not columns
- `register` (in the `WHERE` clause) is ambiguous
- You have a `JOIN` clause after a `WHERE` clause
- You do not specify an alias for the second column of your derived table `a` (perhaps not *necessary* but may cause issues)
- Use of a `?` parameter without a way to specify a value (although this is a limitation of SQL Fiddle and not *necessarily* a problem with your SQL statement)

Comment: I fixed that. Thx but there are still problems (look at the new fiddle)

Comment: Fixed it again. But still a problem that I cant solve:
Unknown column 'realvalues.DeviceID' in 'on clause
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6dc97/38

Comment: I think the `register` is right? I want to match the Register columns

Comment: but order is important. Have You seen my SQLFIDDLE ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33960/discussion-between-daniel-brunner-and-jaczes)

Answer (score 1):

i dont see usage of @start and @end

EDIT: now it works !

sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6dc97/50

Comment: `realvalues`.`Timestamp` IS BETWEEN start AND end

Comment: `@start` isn't the same as `start`